drf-spectacular extend_schema raw data
I´m trying to send a raw data do extend_schema extend_schema decorator to only inform the yml file and create the swagger documentation
def extend_schema_from_yaml(yaml_file_path, operation_id=None):
def decorator(view_func):
    with open(yaml_file_path, "r") as file:
        schema = yaml.safe_load(file)

    summary = schema.get("summary", "")
    description = schema.get("description", "")
    responses = schema.get("responses", {})
    tags = schema.get("tags")

    extend_schema_kwargs = {
        "operation_id": operation_id,
        "summary": summary,
        "description": description,
        "responses": responses,
    }

    if tags:
        extend_schema_kwargs["tags"] = tags

    # Apply extend_schema to the view function
    return extend_schema(**extend_schema_kwargs)(view_func)

return decorator

It´s work for operation_id, summary, description and tags, but not with responses. Any one can help me?
That´s my yml file
tags:
  - "Tag"
summary: "Summary"
description: "Description"
responses:
  "200":
    description: "Numbers"
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            type: integer
          example: [2020, 2021, 2022]


responses:
  "200":
    description: "Numbers"
    type: array
    items:
      type: integer
    example: "[2020, 2021, 2022]"

It´s work

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
